# How can I use platform specific code to share images with a Flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I searched everywhere but came to the conclusion that there is neither any built-in way nor any plugins that can share an image from a Flutter app. So, I thought that the best way to share an image from a Flutter app is to share it with platform specific codes separately for Android and iOS.

The question is; how can I implement platform specific codes to my Flutter app to share images?

I have very little knowledge of native languages so any help is much appreciated. All I need is to share images through the platforms' own share dialogs.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/hathibelagal-dev/launcher-assist-for-flutter/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/progur/launcherassist/LauncherAssistPlugin.java#L66) is an example of sending an image through a platform channel. The image is first converted to bytes and sent through the channel then on the dart end it can be used as `Image.memory(image)`

Comment: And [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2882495-your-own-image-picker-with-flutter-channels) tutorial by raywenderlich.com is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write platform specific code in flutter (native code) and execute them from flutter by using [platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) , using this you can implement any type of native code whether in iOS or Android for e.g. implementing payment gateways and other SDKs that are not available in Dart language. 
I guess this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Writing code is the only way to achieve what you need while creating an application, isn’t is?

Comment: What do you mean by "the concept of questions on StackOverflow"? @creativecreatorormaybenot